# Jekyll JSON errors in commandline?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, terminal, jekyll

I tried to look this up but to no avail. When running Jekyll with "Jekyll serve" I'm getting the following messages in my commandline after which Jekyll runs fine.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_ARRAY
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VERSION_ARRAY was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MAJOR
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/version.rb:5: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MAJOR was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_MINOR
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of VERSION_MINOR was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/version.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant JSON::VERSION_BUILD
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/version.rb:7: warning: previous definition of VERSION_BUILD was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:99: warning: already initialized constant JSON::NaN
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:99: warning: previous definition of NaN was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:101: warning: already initialized constant JSON::Infinity
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:101: warning: previous definition of Infinity was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant JSON::MinusInfinity
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:103: warning: previous definition of MinusInfinity was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:128: warning: already initialized constant JSON::UnparserError
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:128: warning: previous definition of UnparserError was here
```

Jekyll runs fine though! But I guess it couldn't harm to fix this. It probably has something to do with versions of JSON not matching Jekylls dependencies?

Comment: I think this is json version problem. [https://github.com/flori/json/issues/177](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/177)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating all my gems.

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```